# What's the temperature in TGVs?

Tags: trains, france, clothing

I noticed that the French TGVs have no window that can be opened so the temperature is necessarily controlled with the air conditioning.

I am curious, is the air conditioning set to a specific temperature, cold like often in airplanes or a more ambient temperature? I'd like to figure if I should take an extra sweater for my trip. Is it the same temperature in winter and summer?

Comment: The first sentence does not fully make sense to me. I suppose you mean that you can't open them but TGVs obviously have windows and it does matter. Furthermore, even in trains in which you can open the windows, there is usually some air conditioning. When it breaks down or in very old trains you can find in poor countries, the temperatures can get very high indeed.

Comment: Purely one man's opinion, I've always found it to be "just right".  It seems that indeed the train staff can set it, it's not totally corporatized.  When the heating/cooling is broken, it's really a pain.

Comment: Temperature being too cold or too hot is purely an individual opinion.  Likewise for the need to bring a sweater or not.

Comment: The question whether it's too hot or too cold is opinion-based, but the absolute temperature is not.

Comment: When in doubt, bring an extra sweater. You'll regret not bringing it an needing it, but you won't regret bringing it and not needing it.

Comment: Now that the question appears in **Hot** network questions I think you can leave the sweater at home ;-)

Comment: Now that it's winter the heating is cranked to full power. I traveled last weekend comfortably turning the sleeves of my shirt up. Temperature outside was 9°C. In the summer the air conditioning is set to glacial breeze. If you are the cold kind always keep a sweater nearby.

Comment: @Relaxed: Or in very old trains: Never used the regional trains in Germany, haven't you? Their lack of A/C is well known by the travellers...

Comment: @arc_lupus I have, quite frequently, and never really noticed this as being particularly bad. But there are many different types of trains in use, maybe some other regions have older rolling stock? In any case, are you sure they have absolutely no A/C or isn't it just that the A/C is unable to cope with hot weather and/or too many people? This can happen with many trains, in fact I recall one journey where the IC-leg was much worse than the RB train I took afterwards and everybody following the news in Germany has heard of the huge problems faced by ICE trains.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I could not find any official information on how exactly the air conditioning is set (standard temperature? change with the season?) but many people complain that it is too cold (e.g. on the SNCF forum). It's all very subjective but personally I find it OK. However, it is indeed usually on the colder side, even when the weather is good. I would therefore recommend having a sweater on hand, just in case.

Comment: The temperature itself isn't that bad. The real problem is where the air comes from. It comes from vents that are blowing cold air from the bottom of the window, where you place your arm like in an armchair. That air blowing is very uncomfortable. One way to remedy this is to put something to block that air where you want to place your arm. The passengers that are not next to the window are usually fine temperature wise, and have no uncomfortable air blowing all over them.

Answer (score 17):

There is no official temperature setting for TGV trains because this setting is accessible to the conductors which set it to whatever value they find reasonable before the start of the trip. Now, since those guys have to wear full suit uniforms, the temperature that is comfortable for them does not necessarily correspond to the value comfortable for passengers, especially in summer when everyone is wearing T-shirts.

Personally I find this temperature comfortable, but if you know you feel cold before other people do, take extra clothes on the trip.

Comment: (+1) I have read this too, but I could not find any official confirmation anywhere. Also, it's one thing for the controls to be accessible but conductors could nonetheless have specific instructions (that's the case for toilets doors for example). Do you know anything about that?

Comment: I don't think the problem would be in specific instructions (what instruction can there be, other than "keep the temperature comfortable"?). The hard part is to please everyone at once.

Comment: I expect that conductors actually receive the instruction to keep it to a very specific temperature. This is not like a bus where the doors are often opened : a TGV has its doors open for maybe 10-15 minutes over the course of a 3-6 hours ride, so the temperature stays stable to whatever it is set. I see no reason to do otherwise.

Comment: It's not particularly difficult to think of potential instructions: It could be anything from set the system to X°C, with the controls only there as a back-up if something goes wrong, to some sort of table based on the time of the year, the weather or some other factors. Or, indeed, no instructions at all. Surely, the SNCF has the means to determine what the best compromise temperature is instead of asking each conductor to decide what “comfortable” means for them. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Relaxed: This is France, not Germany.

Answer (score 7):

From what I can understand from the TGV FAQ, the temperature tend to be on the colder side.

Morning trains will be colder or hotter (depending on the season) inn the morning as the heater and AC are turned off when the trains are not in use.

http://questions.sncf.com/questions/792206-climatisation-reglee-temperature-basse-tgv

Comment: There is a bunch of questions on this site but it seems to be mostly passengers discussing with each other, no official word either way.

Answer (score 5):

Approximately,and given the similarities (and that nowadays there's a barcelona-paris direct trip) , i'll base my response on the AVE, spanish TGV :

During summer, the temperature is set between 18 and 22ºC depending on the temperature outside ( the higher outside, the lower) , counting that a lot of people generate a lot of temperature and that human odour is less noticeable on cold air, and during winter, it's set between 20 and 25ºC. Atleast on the spanish trains tho, there's a display that constantly shows current weather, next stop, current outside temperature, current inside temperature, etc...

but yes, in general, and for the average person, it's cold. it's meant to be cold because it's better to keep people not sweating too much in a closed , plane-sized cabin without showers, for long streaks of time.

that black thing above the door is the data screen:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. There existence of a direct train between two countries is no reason at all to assume that a train company based in one of the countries keeps its trains at the same temperature as that used by a different company, on different trains, in the other country.

Comment: that's why i start with "Approximately", because it won't be accurate.

Comment: Having said that, I agree that it makes sense to have trains slightly cold, since a carriage full of sweaty people is unpleasant and it's easier to put more clothes on than to take clothes off.

Comment: For all i know, both companies share drivers, trains, and crew all along the madrid - paris line, so it might be reasonable, althought completely made up by me, for them to have similar or almost identical cabin temperatures on both high-speed train services.

Comment: Oh, come on. They _might be_ similar temperatures for all kinds of reasons. But that doesn't mean that they _are_ similar. It's just complete supposition on your part. We're looking for answers, not plausible guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly : Be grateful you cant open the windows at those speeds. The wind could really mess your hair....remove teeth...

Here is an article ( in French )

http://transports.blog.lemonde.fr/2013/07/10/tous-nos-trains-sont-climatises-assure-la-sncf-ou-presque/

You can drop the link in to Google Translate and also discover why its quicker to learn a language than wait for Google to come up with a reliable translation engine.

Yes they ALL have aircon from super-sunny-hot South through the frigid High-Alps to the wet and clammy North.  The conductor can change the settings. He/she may deny this because keeping a trainload of people happy is not a task for the timid.